# SQl to determine if I have INSERT permission on employee table

Tags: sql, insert, permissions

I was wondering what the SQL query would be to determine if I had the INSERT permission on for eg. an Employee table?

How can i ask the sql server this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per MSDN documentation, the syntax for granting different kinds of permissions is

```
GRANT <permission> [ ,...n ] ON 
    [ OBJECT :: ][ schema_name ]. object_name [ ( column [ ,...n ] ) ]
    TO <database_principal> [ ,...n ] 
    [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
    [ AS <database_principal> ]

<permission> ::=
    ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] | permission [ ( column [ ,...n ] ) ]

<database_principal> ::= Database_user 
    | Database_role 
    | Application_role 
    | Database_user_mapped_to_Windows_User 
    | Database_user_mapped_to_Windows_Group 
    | Database_user_mapped_to_certificate 
    | Database_user_mapped_to_asymmetric_key 
    | Database_user_with_no_login
```

So following the syntax, the INSERT permission on the Employee Table can be granted to a user like this

```
GRANT INSERT ON <your db name>.Employee TO <username>
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can just view the table to see IF i have the permission? @Rahil051